# Compiling QEMU on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: osx-lion, compile, qemu

I've been having trouble compiling a working copy of QEMU on Lion.

When I try installing through homebrew, I get a screen like this when I attempt to run QEMU:

[image: blank qemu screen]

The blank screen just sits there hogging the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the Lion compatibility issues are solved.  I'm still testing this: http://www.rpiforum.net/forum/tutorials/article/16-a-raspberry-pi-emulated-environment-on-osx-lion/

Answer (score 0):

Please try the latest v1.1.0 Release Candidate from http://wiki.qemu.org/Download.

If that does not solve it, post to qemu-devel mailing list how exactly you configure and run it.

Comment: I had a compile error with 1.1.0-rc3, but I've emailed the mailing list with my fix